css shadowEffect differences on web vs mobile (React Native)
I am building a React native application and working on the tabs style. A Tab.Screen looks like this:
<Tabs.Screen
        name="events"
        options={{
          title: "Events",
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused }: any) => (
            <View style={focused ? styles.shadowEffect : null}>
              {focused && <View style={styles.activeBar} />}
              <Ionicons
                name="calendar-clear-outline"
                size={32}
                color={focused ? colors.black : colors.btm_nav_unselected}
              />
            </View>
          ),
          tabBarLabel: ({ focused }: any) => (
            <Text
              style={{
                fontFamily: "Lexend-Regular",
                color: focused ? colors.black : colors.btm_nav_unselected,
                fontSize: 12,
              }}
            >
              Events
            </Text>
          ),
        }}
      />

The StyleSheet is as below:
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  shadowEffect: {
    ...Platform.select({
      ios: {
        shadowColor: colors.secondary,
        shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 5 },
        shadowOpacity: 0.15,
        shadowRadius: 50, // Reduce radius for mobile consistency
      },
      android: {
        shadowColor: colors.secondary,
        shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 3 },
        shadowOpacity: 0.15,
        shadowRadius: 5,
      },
      web: {
        shadowColor: colors.secondary,
        shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 5 },
        shadowRadius: 50,
      },
    }),
    backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 122, 255, 0.17)",
    borderRadius: 20,
    padding: 1,
  },
  activeBar: {
    ...Platform.select({
      web: {
        position: "absolute",
        top: -8,
        left: "50%", // Start in the center
        transform: [{ translateX: -15 }], // Offset to center the active bar
        width: 30, // Fixed width for consistency across tabs
        height: 8,
        backgroundColor: colors.fitness_tab,
        borderTopLeftRadius: 8,
        borderTopRightRadius: 8,
        borderBottomLeftRadius: 0,
        borderBottomRightRadius: 0,
      },
      android: {
        position: "absolute",
        top: -8,
        left: -3, // Start in the center
        width: 30, // Fixed width for consistency across tabs
        height: 8,
        backgroundColor: colors.fitness_tab,
        borderTopLeftRadius: 8,
        borderTopRightRadius: 8,
        borderBottomLeftRadius: 0,
        borderBottomRightRadius: 0,
      },
    }),
  },
});

The reason I have created different styles based on platform is because the same rules don't apply on all platforms. For example, with the current code, I am getting this appearance on the web:

Whereas, on mobile (android) I have this appearance:

On android the shadow is very dense and dark.
How could I achieve a similar shadow appearance on Android to the one on the web?
Thanks in advance!
